# How to access Dual boot when Grub is corrupted?

Tags: boot, grub

I tried to delete my partitions of Ubuntu to Dual boot elementary, and now I can only access Windows with <kbd>F12</kbd>.
If I let it boot, it says "minimal bash like script...".
In my boot entries on <kbd>F1</kbd>, I get:

`Grub(takes me to minimal bash)
 Apricity(previous os which I removed partition for)
 Ubuntu(takes me to minimal bash)
 Windows`

I dont know what to do anymore. I have tried updating grub to no avail. I have searched for hours on how to fix this, but nothing has worked. Please help me.

Comment: follow the answer below or you can follow the MBR steps over here http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-safely-uninstall-ubuntu-in-windows-dual-boot-environment/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the answer from https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on/143482#143482

It will help you restore the windows MBR The Master Boot record. You need to follow the first set of steps only since you have already removed your ubuntu partition.

---

> To remove Ubuntu, you will need a Windows Recovery CD or Installation
>   CD, or a Ubuntu Live CD.
>
> **Note:**  If you don't have a Windows Installation or Recovery CD available, you can download the Windows 7 ISO file (contact Digital
>   River customer support as [said in Microsoft help page](http://drh.img.digitalriver.com/store/mswpus/ContentTheme/pbPage.Upgrade)).  You
>   cannot install Windows without a genuine Purchased Product Key though,
>   as these ISO files are 100% legal and will only install as an
>   Evaluation copy for 30 days without a product key.
>
> To remove GRUB:
>
> 1. Grab a Windows recovery media or installation CD and boot from it.  You should see this on a **recovery media** CD.
>
>    [image: System Recovery Options dialog]
>
>    And you should see this on an **installation media** CD.  Click
>      "Repair your computer" and you should see a screen like the first
>      image. [image: Image from bleepingcomputer.com]
> 2. Open the Command Prompt, then type `bootrec /fixmbr` into the Command Prompt.
>
>    [image: Command prompt FIXMBR]
> 3. Reboot and boot into Windows.  Then follow the steps below to remove the Ubuntu partitions.
>
>    (Images from [HowtoGeek](http://www.howtogeek.com))
>
> > ### Till here might do your work rest is bonus
>
> ---
>
> If you don't have a Windows recovery CD or you are constrained to
>   download and burn the ISO files mentioned before, you can use
>   [Boot-repair](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/).  It is a tool that fixes most boot problems(Windows
>   or Ubuntu).  I suggest using a Windows CD if possible.
>
> To use boot repair:
>
> 1. Boot from a Ubuntu live CD or USB
> 2. Type these lines in the terminal one line at a time.
>
>    ```
>    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
>    sudo apt-get update
>    sudo apt-get install boot-repair
>    ```
> 3. Search for Boot-Repair in the Dash and launch it.
>
>    [image: Boot repair dialog]
>
>    To fix your computer with Boot-repair, simply click the "Recommended
>      Repair" button.  Then follow the steps below to remove the Ubuntu
>      Partitions.
>
> ---
>
> To delete the Ubuntu Partitions:
>
> 4. Go to Start, right click Computer, then select Manage.  Then select Disk Management from the sidebar.
>
>    [image: Disk Management]
> 5. Right-click your Ubuntu partitions and select "Delete". **Check before you delete!**
> 6. Then, right-click the partition that is on the Left of the free space.  Select "Extend Volume".  Go through the Wizard and Finish it. 
>      [image: Extend Volume Wizard]
> 7. Done!
>
> Another note from [Tanner](https://askubuntu.com/users/76265/tanner): If you are using an extended
>   partition, you might have to remove the big extended partition to make
>   the space unallocated.